# Catch error's command lines while executing multiple inserts in a single sqlcommand

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlcommand

i have to automate executing of **multiple `sql` insert commands** in a single `sqlcommand` of my application , and I have to keep insert commands which cloud not execute (because of errors) in  executed **c#'s `sqlcommand`** .
By the way i don't want that errors suppress continuing the query execution.

any suggestions?

thank you

Comment: please tell us what you have done already

Comment: @pinusnegra: approximately nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use try catch in SQL statement

see [this MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179296.aspx) and [CodeProject link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/ErrorHandling.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can do a for or for each loop on all available commands to execute: inside this loop you put a try catch and in the catch block you log/report the exception but do not throw so the loop will continue with next iteration.

Notice that you could also use SqlBulk objects to do many inserts in a way similar to what you describe.

**Edit:**

if this is to slow you can definitely use the `SqlBulkCopy`: check here for a step by step example: [Bulk Insert into SQL from C# App](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nikhilsi/archive/2008/06/11/bulk-insert-into-sql-from-c-app.aspx)

Comment: what is slow? can you write a bit more words in your sentence?

Comment: trying the query and catch errors for each line , in a loop in c# is too slow when i have 35179 lines , which each one is a single insert

Answer (score 0):

this worked

```
void ConvertCsv(string sourcePath, string ResultPath)
{


    #region
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(sourcePath))
    {
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ResultPath))
        {
            sw.WriteLine(@"DECLARE @er NVARCHAR(MAX)='',@i INT=0 BEGIN  TRY");
            if (sr.Peek() >= 0)
            {
                string currentLine = sr.ReadLine();

                while (currentLine.Trim() == "" && sr.Peek() >= 0)
                    currentLine = sr.ReadLine();
                if (currentLine.Trim() == "")
                {
                    //error :the file is empty
                }
                sw.WriteLine(currentLine);

            }

            while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
            {
                string currentLine = sr.ReadLine();

                if (currentLine.Trim() == "")
                    continue;
                if (currentLine.Trim().StartsWith("INSERT"))
                {
                    while (!currentLine.Trim().StartsWith("INSERT"))
                        currentLine += sr.ReadLine();
                    currentLine = @"END TRY
                                                    BEGIN CATCH
                                                    SELECT @er+=','+LTRIM(RTRIM(STR(ERROR_LINE()))),@i+=1
                                                END CATCH BEGIN  TRY" + Environment.NewLine + currentLine.Trim();

                }
                sw.WriteLine(currentLine.Trim());
            }
            sw.WriteLine(@"END TRY
                                        BEGIN CATCH
                                        SELECT @er+=','+LTRIM(RTRIM(STR(ERROR_LINE())))
                                    END CATCH SELECT @er AS errorLines,@i AS errorCount");
            sw.Close();
            sr.Close();

        }
    }
    #endregion
    ExecuteConvertedFile(ResultPath,Server.MapPath(@"~/Data/Uploads/csv/ErrorLogs/ErrorLog.sql"));
}

void ExecuteConvertedFile(string ResultPath, string errorResultPath)
{
    string wholeQuery = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(ResultPath);
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand { CommandType = CommandType.Text, CommandText = wholeQuery, Connection = new SqlConnection(((SqlConnection)((EntityConnection)new NezaratEntities().Connection).StoreConnection).ConnectionString) })
    {
        cmd.Connection.Open();
        var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        dr.Read();

        WriteErrorLogs(ResultPath,errorResultPath,dr["errorLines"].ToString().Trim());
        Label1.Text = dr["errorCount"].ToString()+"unsuccessful transactions";

    }
}
```

to save unsuccessful sql commands:

```
void WriteErrorLogs(string sourcePath, string ResultPath,string errorLinesTolog)
{
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(sourcePath);
    string ErrorLog="";
    errorLinesTolog=errorLinesTolog.Remove(0, 1);

    foreach (var line in errorLinesTolog.Split(','))
    {
        ErrorLog += lines[int.Parse(line)-1] + Environment.NewLine;
    }
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(ResultPath, ErrorLog);
}
```